# Metadata for matching filter for sObject

Tags: rest-api, opportunity, sobject, describesobject, workbench

I'm trying to find the metadata for the matching filter for any sObject in my case its 'Opportunity' is that possible to find out the what the filter matching creatria is? using REST API

I have played with workbench using the REST explorer:

> /services/data/v39.0/sobjects/opportunity/describe

but I did not get information which I'm looking for.

Shown below in the screen shot, I'm trying to find matching filter criteria is:

[image]

Comment: have you looked into the listview describe call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SOQL I don't think this is possible but using listview describe you will get the all details check this out

> List View Describe Returns detailed information about a list view,
>   including the ID, the columns, and the SOQL query. This resource is
>   available in REST API version 32.0 and later.
>
> URI /vXX.X/sobjects/{sobjectType}/listviews/{queryLocator}/describe
>
> ```
> {
>   "columns" : [ {
>     "ascendingLabel" : "Z-A",
>     "descendingLabel" : "A-Z",
>     "fieldNameOrPath" : "Name",
>     "hidden" : false,
>     "label" : "Account Name",
>     "selectListItem" : "Name",
>     "sortDirection" : "ascending",
>     "sortIndex" : 0,
>     "sortable" : true,
>     "type" : "string"
>   }, {
>     "ascendingLabel" : "Z-A",
>     "descendingLabel" : "A-Z",
>     "fieldNameOrPath" : "Site",
>     "hidden" : false,
>     "label" : "Account Site",
>     "selectListItem" : "Site",
>     "sortDirection" : null,
>     "sortIndex" : null,
>     "sortable" : true,
>     "type" : "string"
>   }, {
>     "ascendingLabel" : "Z-A",
>     "descendingLabel" : "A-Z",
>     "fieldNameOrPath" : "BillingState",
>     "hidden" : false,
>     "label" : "Billing State/Province",
>     "selectListItem" : "BillingState",
>     "sortDirection" : null,
>     "sortIndex" : null,
>     "sortable" : true,
>     "type" : "string"
>   }, {
>     "ascendingLabel" : "9-0",
>     "descendingLabel" : "0-9",
>     "fieldNameOrPath" : "Phone",
>     "hidden" : false,
>     "label" : "Phone",
>     "selectListItem" : "Phone",
>     "sortDirection" : null,
>     "sortIndex" : null,
>     "sortable" : true,
>     "type" : "phone"
>   }, {
>     "ascendingLabel" : "Low to High",
>     "descendingLabel" : "High to Low",
>     "fieldNameOrPath" : "Type",
>     "hidden" : false,
>     "label" : "Type",
>     "selectListItem" : "toLabel(Type)",
>     "sortDirection" : null,
>     "sortIndex" : null,
>     "sortable" : true,
>     "type" : "picklist"
>   }, {
>     "ascendingLabel" : "Z-A",
>     "descendingLabel" : "A-Z",
>     "fieldNameOrPath" : "Owner.Alias",
>     "hidden" : false,
>     "label" : "Account Owner Alias",
>     "selectListItem" : "Owner.Alias",
>     "sortDirection" : null,
>     "sortIndex" : null,
>     "sortable" : true,
>     "type" : "string"
>   }, {
>     "ascendingLabel" : null,
>     "descendingLabel" : null,
>     "fieldNameOrPath" : "Id",
>     "hidden" : true,
>     "label" : "Account ID",
>     "selectListItem" : "Id",
>     "sortDirection" : null,
>     "sortIndex" : null,
>     "sortable" : false,
>     "type" : "id"
>   }, {
>     "ascendingLabel" : null,
>     "descendingLabel" : null,
>     "fieldNameOrPath" : "CreatedDate",
>     "hidden" : true,
>     "label" : "Created Date",
>     "selectListItem" : "CreatedDate",
>     "sortDirection" : null,
>     "sortIndex" : null,
>     "sortable" : false,
>     "type" : "datetime"
>   }, {
>     "ascendingLabel" : null,
>     "descendingLabel" : null,
>     "fieldNameOrPath" : "LastModifiedDate",
>     "hidden" : true,
>     "label" : "Last Modified Date",
>     "selectListItem" : "LastModifiedDate",
>     "sortDirection" : null,
>     "sortIndex" : null,
>     "sortable" : false,
>     "type" : "datetime"
>   }, {
>     "ascendingLabel" : null,
>     "descendingLabel" : null,
>     "fieldNameOrPath" : "SystemModstamp",
>     "hidden" : true,
>     "label" : "System Modstamp",
>     "selectListItem" : "SystemModstamp",
>     "sortDirection" : null,
>     "sortIndex" : null,
>     "sortable" : false,
>     "type" : "datetime"
>   } ],
>   "id" : "00BD0000005WcBe",
>   "orderBy" : [ {
>     "fieldNameOrPath" : "Name",
>     "nullsPosition" : "first",
>     "sortDirection" : "ascending"
>   }, {
>     "fieldNameOrPath" : "Id",
>     "nullsPosition" : "first",
>     "sortDirection" : "ascending"
>   } ],
>   "query" : "SELECT name, site, billingstate, phone, tolabel(type), 
>      owner.alias, id, createddate, lastmodifieddate,
>    systemmodstamp FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_WEEK ORDER BY
>    Name ASC NULLS FIRST, Id ASC NULLS FIRST",
>   "scope" : null,
>   "sobjectType" : "Account",
>   "whereCondition" : {
>     "field" : "CreatedDate",
>     "operator" : "equals",
>     "values" : [ "THIS_WEEK" ]
>   }
> }
> ```